# Write the negation of the following

Tags: logic

$P(x,y)$ is the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$

$ \forall\  y\  \neg P(2,y)$

I solved this is it correct?

$$\neg P(2,0) \wedge P(2,1) \wedge P(2,2) \wedge  P(2,3) \wedge P(2,4) \wedge P(2,5)$$

Comment: $P(x,y)$ should be a set of ordered pairs, not a set of numbers.

Comment: $P(x,y)$ is **not** the set ... The set ... is the *domain* of the interpretation  you are using to "evaluate" $P(x,y)$.

Answer (score 1):

This question leads to [Open world assumption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-world_assumption). According to the definition of OWA, anything that is not stated as false explicitly, then it's not false. In the definition, you are defining P(x,y) and not $\neg$ P(x,y). So whatever be the definition of P(x,y), if you query $ \forall y \neg P(2,y) $, then result is empty. If you have definition of $\neg P(2,y)$, then you get some results there.

Answer (score 0):

If the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is a **domain of discourse**, and $P(x,y)$ is a **predicate** with two arguments from that domain, then :

$$\forall y\; \neg P(2,y) \;\iff\; \neg P(2,0)\wedge \neg P(2,1)\wedge \neg P(2,2) \wedge \neg P(2,3)\wedge \neg P(2,4)\wedge \neg P(2, 5)$$

Comment: Or for brevity: $\neg[P(2,0)\vee P(2,1)\vee P(2,2)\vee P(2,3)\vee P(2,4)\vee P(2,5)]$